# Summernote: Enable Air-mode along with the default toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

Is there a way to enable both the default toolbar and the air-mode toolbar in summernote editor ?

For example I need the user to edit the textarea with the default toolbar at first, and when he wants to edit just one word he can select it and the air-mode toolbar pops up. *(just like Microsoft word for example)*

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this thing by going and editing the source code of summernote and rebuilding it *(requires npm)*. 
It was quite easy you just need to edit only two files and make a build.
**Download/Clone the summernote-develop source code**.
https://github.com/summernote/summernote
**Follow these steps**
1. Open folder `summernote-develop`
2. Open `src/js/bs3/module/Toolbar.js`

*You will find line as*

```
this.shouldInitialize = function () {
          return !options.airMode;
        };
```

*this code actually checks for airMode if its true then it doesn't initialize the toolbar, now change the code to*

```
this.shouldInitialize = function () {
      return true;
    };
```

*and save it.*

3.Open `src/js/bs3/ui.js`

*You will find this code typically at line number 176.*

```
var $editor = (options.airMode ? ui.airEditor([
    ui.editingArea([
        ui.airEditable()
    ])
    ]) : ui.editor([
             ui.toolbar(),
             ui.editingArea([
                 ui.codable(),
                 ui.editable()
          ]),
          ui.statusbar()
     ])).render();
```

*this code typically checks for airMode and load the UI accordingly, we need to load the traditional UI whatever airMode says. Change this to*

```
var $editor = (ui.editor([
        ui.toolbar(),
        ui.editingArea([
          ui.codable(),
          ui.editable()
        ]),
        ui.statusbar()
      ])).render();
```

*this will load traditional summernote ui.*
4. Now we have to **rebuild** the whole project to **generate the required js file**, on the terminal *execute these commands*

`summernote-develop username $ npm install`

```
summernote-develop username $ npm run build
```

5. Navigate to **dist** folder in the **summernote-develop**, *required js file will be generated there*.

**note**: dont forget to enable airMode while initializing summernote i.e. *airMode: true*